# Import JSON file from URL into R

Tags: json, r

I've been trying to import a JSON file into R for a while using both the rjson and RJSONIO package, but I can't get it to work. One of the variations of code I used:

```
json_file <- "http://toolserver.org/~emw/index.php?c=rawdata&m=get_traffic_data&p1=USA&project1=en&from=12/10/2007&to=4/1/2011"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

This results in an error message:

```
Error in fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse = "")) : 
unexpected character '<'
```

I think the problem is in the first line of code, because json_file contains the source of the website, not the actual content. I've tried getURL() and getURLContent(), but without any success. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: as pointed out by Martin Morgan, the problem seems to be with the URL, not the code!

Comment: When I visit the url in my browser and view the page source, it _is_ pure HTML, with no JSON. So

Comment: Thanks for checking! You're right, but what is displayed on the page is JSON. Do you know of a way to grab that? I've tried some functions in the RCurl package, but without any luck so far.

Comment: Previously, typing the URL into the browser would generate a blank page and `fromJSON(json_file)` would error as you indicate. Just now, the browser displays JSON, and `library(RJSONIO); fromJSON(json_file)` works as expected. It seems like the service is not behaving consistently, either because of an issue on 'their' end or because it is meant to be invoked in a more subtle way than just pointing at a URL

Comment: Oh wow, it does work with this URL! I'll contact the owner of the tool. Thanks so much for following up!

Answer (score 4):

```
library(rjson)
fromJSON(readLines('http://toolserver.org/~emw/index.php?c=rawdata&m=get_traffic_data&p1=USA&project1=en&from=12/10/2007&to=4/1/2011')[1])
```

works for me, with a warning