# How do I pull .js or .json data from a specific URL into an R data frame

Tags: json, r, rjsonio

I have been trying to pull data from this specific URL: http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js using RJSONIO.  I went to that URL and saved the data by pressing CTRL+A to select all of the data there and then pasted it into notepad++, saving it as test.json.  Here is what I have tried in R from that point:

```
library(RJSONIO)
json_file <- dir("test.json")
jsonIntoR <- fromJSON(readLines(json_file)[1])
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in fromJSON(readLines(json_file)[1]) : 
    error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
```

I'd like to convert the data at this URL into a dataframe, but have not been able to overcome this error.  I have tried using the solution at this link: [Import JSON file from URL into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542300/import-json-file-from-url-into-r) but it does not work for me.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `readLines(...)`.

```
library(rjson)
library(httr)
url <- "http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js"
text <- content(GET(url),type="text")
text <- sub("var statesData = ","",text)
text <- sub(";$","",text)
json <- fromJSON(text)
```

Your file is actually javascript, so to make it interpretable as json you need to strip off the leadling `var statesData =` and the trailing `;`.